# Tkinter window cutting off button

Tags: python, tkinter

A new problem for me - I think related to updating Tkinter version - is that I am having buttons getting cut off on the sides of windows at times (see screenshot). What's causing this/what's the solution? I've tried adjusting the window geometry, but it doesn't seem to affect anything now. The button is the proper size, so dragging the window to the right reveals the whole thing. It's a window size issue.

[image]

```
def GetReDate():

    chosendate = ''.join([str(datetime.date.today().month).zfill(2),'/',str(datetime.date.today().day).zfill(2)])

    PickDatewin = Toplevel()
    PickDatewin.geometry('400x50')
    PickDatewin.title("Choose a Date")
    L1 = Label(PickDatewin, text="Date: ")
    L1.pack(side = LEFT)
    E1 = Entry(PickDatewin, bd =5)
    E1.pack(side = LEFT)
    E1.delete(0, END)
    E1.insert(0, chosendate)
    OK = Button(PickDatewin, text='Choose', command=lambda:ChooseDate(E1,chosendate,PickDatewin))
    OK.pack(side = RIGHT)
```

Comment: I've tested this on Windows 10 with Python 3.6 and it behaves as expected, the button is not cut off, possibly an OS/version issue? What OS and Python version are you using?

Comment: OS X Sierra, Python 2.7.9. The issue started when I migrated to a new computer, so there are lots of variables.

Comment: Do you have the ability to test this in 3.6? Or perhaps on another Mac?

Comment: I don't have those at hand, but the issue didn't happen with my previous Python 2.7 installation

Comment: Was that also on Mac?

Comment: Yes; it was Mavericks

Answer (score 0):

The reason has to do with the fact that the widgets have a preferred size, but the widgets won't fit in the window. When tkinter can no longer draw all widgets at their minimum requested size it starts shrinking widgets, starting with the last widget to be packed.

Different platforms (and possibly, different users) may have different defaults for fonts and border widths and so on, but you aren't taking that into consideration when you hard-code the dialog to a specific size. Thus, the natural size of the widgets is larger than the window size you requested, so tkinter does its best to make them fit by shrinking the last widget to be packed.

Arguably, the best solution is to not force the window to a specific size. Instead, let tkinter compute the size based on the widgets inside the window.

Another simple solution is to make sure the widget that is the most flexible is the last to be packed, so that it is the first widget to be shrunk when the widgets don't all fit.

Notice the difference between your original code which chops off the button:

```
OK.pack(side = RIGHT)
L1.pack(side = LEFT)
E1.pack(side = LEFT)
```

... with this code, which chops off the more flexible entry widget:

```
L1.pack(side = LEFT)
E1.pack(side = LEFT)
OK.pack(side = RIGHT)
```

For a thorough description of how `pack` works, see [The Packer Algorithm](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/pack.htm#M26) in the official tk documentation (upon which tkinter is based).